# Passing byte[] as a single parameter to a vararg method

Tags: java, arrays, variadic-functions

I have a method which has a varargs parameter. It looks like this:

```
public void sampleFunction(String name, Object... args) {

}
```

I want to pass a `byte[]` to this method, but as a single parameter. How can I do this?

```
byte[] myByteArray = functionReturningAByteArray();

sampleFunction("Name", myByteArray);
```

Will this be considered as an array or, will `myByteArray` is considered as a single object?

When I passed the `byte[]`, IntelliJ reports it as `Confusing primitive array argument to varargs method`. I tried to cast `myByteArray` to an `Object` as it suggested, then it reports it as redundant cast.

I want to pass it as a single object.

Comment: Have you tried it? `byte[]` is not an `Object[]` so it should work fine.

Comment: I did not tried it, IntelliJ reported this as a `Confusing primitive array argument to varargs method`. That's why I got confused

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A `byte[]` is a primitive array, so it is definitely not an `Object[]`. Therefore, it will be passed as a single `Object` instance to your vararg method.

If, on the other hand, you would pass a `Byte[]` array, it will be passed as multiple `Object` arguments to the vararg method.

Of course, you can verify this for yourself:

```
public static void sampleFunction(String name, Object... args) {
    System.out.println (args.length);
}

sampleFunction("x", new byte[] {1,2,3});
sampleFunction("x", new Byte[] {1,2,3});
```

The first call prints `1`, while the second call prints `3`.

Comment: I'm just curious - there is no option to achieve the same with an actual `Object[]`, right? Lets say I want to pass two different `Object` arrays to the function, I won't be able to tell where the first one ends? I guess I'd have to convert those into some `Collection`s?

Comment: @Amongalen I'm not sure I'm following what you are asking. Do you wish to replace the `Object...` with `Object[]`? In that case you wouldn't be able to pass a primitive array as the second argument.

Comment: @Eran To the function with `Object...` I want to pass two `Object[]`

Comment: @Amongalen you could replace the `Object...` arg with two `Object[]` args, but as I said, you wouldn't be able to pass primitive arrays to the method.

Comment: I don't want to change function's definition. Instead, I want to call it as `sampleFunction("x", new Byte[] {1,2,3},new Byte[] {4,5,6});`. Actually I've tested it right now and it turns out that `args.length` would be `2` in this case. Interesting.

Comment: @Amongalen Oh, in that case the vararg method will receive a 2D array of 2 elements. Each element would be an array of length 3.